# Compiling is really slow even with antivirus turned off

Tags: windows, gcc, time, compilation

Compiling is really slow in all development environments I'm using. Mostly GCC for ARM and AVR. Creating (building) and deleting (cleaning) seems what is slowing the processes down. Simple projects takes many minutes to compile. Arduino projects, too, which I guess is GCC.

I've uninstalled F-Secure antivirus and disabled Windows Defender real-time scanning. I've run Windows Defender Offline scan to check for malware and other problems. Something is hogging the process still, and I'm seeing no improvement. How do I go about to find out with delays file-creation and deletion?

EDIT: Computer is fairly quick i7-5600U @ 2.60 GHz, 16GB ram and 64-bit Windows 10. While compiling there is not much physical memory or cpu used, almost nothing.

EDIT: This code takes 46 seconds to compile using AVR-GCC:

```
#undef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 3686400UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void) {
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    while(1) {
        PORTB ^= 0xFF;
        _delay_ms(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: How long does 'hello world' take to compile? In what environment are you working? Try compiling from the CMD with gcc and see if that's slow as well - that way you can narrow down your question.

Comment: Are your disks ok? Probably defragment your hard drive?

Comment: @kabanus The program below took 46 seconds to compile in both command line and Programmers Notepad (PN) which I use for AVR development. When compiling in PN it simply executes a batch script. I develop for STM32 (ARM) in Eclipse, and for TI ARM processors in Code Composer Studio (also eclipse). Please see the code properly formatted in my original post.
`#undef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 3686400UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void) {
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    while(1) {
        PORTB ^= 0xFF;
        _delay_ms(100);
    }
}`

Comment: @ks1322 I'm not sure. Is there a tool I can use to check and/or fix this?

Comment: Yes, see here, for example: https://www.maketecheasier.com/check-hard-disk-health-windows/.

Comment: @ks1322 Now tried all options in the link you provided. They all report back good hdd health and zero problems.

Comment: Try removing each include, and see if one of them is the problem specifically (maybe avr?). Also try a different compiler so we can exclude that (mingw?)

Comment: Thanks @kabanus. I've tried compiling an empty project now, only main function and empty while loop. Nothing changed. I have this problem across all IDE's, projects and compilers I use, so I suspect something checks each file I make/edit/delete, as is usually the case when antivirus software makes compiling slower.

Comment: Last chance, post an image of the running processes before, during and after compilation (sorted by ram and cpu usage). I'm no expert but maybe someone here is.

Comment: What do you mean by image of the process? In task manager? 
I the meantime, I've unmounted all network drives since this was a known culprit on avr gcc, I learned, and done a full virus scan.

Comment: @kabanus did you mean to screenshot the process in task manager?

Comment: Yes, that may give a clue if something is being suspicious during compilation. I admit I'm new network/OS manager, but maybe someone who sees those images can help.